# Remove more than two carriage returns in textarea form?

Tags: php, textarea, preg-replace, carriage-return, nl2br

I spent hours looking at dozens of different solutions but none of them worked. I am receiving the content of a textarea in a php string and I would like to remove anything which is more than one blank line.

```
Example ok
Hi how are you, 
// one blank line here so ok to keep
Not too bad thanks

Example not ok
hi how are you
// two lines (or more) here so we remove one and keep the other

not too bad thanks
```

Does someone know the proper preg_replace to use? Note that I don't want to modify the data (no nl2br() please) as it is easier for me to keep it raw (ios support).

Comment: What about this: `/\n(\n)+/g`

Comment: I already tried to replace /\n\n+/ by \n\n but did not work ... I'm not sure what is the character used for new lines & returns in textareas ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should try this:

```
preg_replace('/\n\r(\n\r)+/', "\n\r", $str);
```

Comment: No idea why that would work but it works. I found it clearer like this though preg_replace('/[\n\r]{2,}/', "\n\r", $str); Thanks a lot!

Comment: This expression finds more than one new lines, and replaces the the second one to the end with one new line. Your welcome, also!

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", "\n", $text);
```

It replaces one (or more) newline or carriage return with a single newline.

Comment: this prevents example 1 (ok) to happen as there is no blank line anymore between the two lines. I tried with /[\r\n]{2,}/ but same ...

Comment: It should work in both cases. Are you sure that you do not need the carriage return in addition to the newline?